# Is posible to extract a <img> from a string?

Tags: android, html, string, extract

I've a String variable with HTML code inside from a RSSParser, the problem is that I use this string with a webWiew and the RSS from blogspot is a mess and it's showing the text at the same level that the image, leaving a big space between a word and the rest of the text.

I've tried to apply a css stylesheet which work, but the image keeps the same due the style in the html code.

The images have this URL:

```
< a href="imageurl.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clear:right; float:right; margin-bottom: 1em;<img src="imageurl.jpg"></img></a>
```

I just want to take that line (because all the images have the same structure) and put it above the text.

My WebView setup:

```
WebView wview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = vista.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    wview.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

A content variable example:

```
<div style="text-align:justify;">
<a href="http://image.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clean:right; float:right; 
margin-bottom: 1em; margin-left:1em;"<img border="0" height="320" src="http://image.jpg" width="240" /></a>

FROM HERE TO END, IT'S JUST PLAIN TEXT. I replaced the URL from the image for one more "normal", the ones from blogspot are a mess.
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your HTML is not valid. You are missing a close bracket '>' before the <img tag.

Comment: No, thanks, It's just a bad copy error. The image is visible, but with a wrong alignement, I mean, you can see the first word of the paragraph in the left top, and the image between it and the rest of the paragraph

Comment: It might have to do with your float then. Can you create a fiddle or paste the entire contents of how to reproduce what you are seeing? It would help to  give you a solution.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute to edit the OP. I'll tell you. Thanks.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can override inline html styles in your CSS by adding the !important declaration to your CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like what I suspected. The `float: right;` css on the `<a` tag is what is causing the text to wrap itself around the image. Depending on your screen width it will either place the image to the right beside the text (if screen is wide), or cause some words to be above the image, and others to be below it (if screen is skinny/narrow).

If you are building the HTML yourself, just remove the `float: right;`. However, if the HTML around the image is coming from an external source, then you're going to have to try to modify it somehow. **Since the `float: right` is right on the `<a` tag you will need to provide `!important` on the style sheet property to override it since, due to CSS rules, attributes right on the tag take precedence.**

So you will need to pre-process the html (remove all float references in code, prior to loading the HTML), provide some custom CSS, or write some javascript to alter the DOM after it has been rendered. If you want to use javascript, something like the following will work, if you can inject javascript code into your page:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach(function(pTag) { pTag.style.float = 'none'; });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try in a different way:

I set to true the webview JavaScript then I concatenate your function in a <script> tag with my string. And then put the !important on my css.

Can it work?

Comment: You should only need to do one of them. Either put !important on the css for float: none; like so: `float: none !important;` (assuming your css class properly selects the image OR use the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, None of that (at least my javascript solution works). Nonetheless, I put the padding-right: 50 and !important. It's a shitty solution, but It's working...at least